# Python - Create an object using the base members of another related object

Tags: python, polymorphism

I have the following situation:

**Animal** class - Base class
Local Member - Name
Local Member - DoesWalk

**Cat** class of type Animal
**Dog** class of type Animal

Let's say I have a cat instantiated with all of it's members.
Is there a way to generate a `Dog` object using the local members of the instantiated cat (to avoid giving every parameter one by one)?

This is just an example, in my case I have much more local members in the base class and I want to avoid giving them one by one.

Comment: Do you want to generate a Dog _class_ or a Dog _object_ using the local members of the _instantiated_ cat ? Please fix the typo if needed

Comment: Sry, it was a dog object, my bad, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

take look at this , by super you can choose what to inherit :

```
class Book:
 def __init__(self,title,author):
  self.title = title
  self.author = author

class Ebook(Book):
 def __init__(self,title,format):
  super().__init__(title) #this is way one
  #super(Ebool,self).__init__(title) # this is way 2, same as previous line
  self.format = format
```